# Debian testing + LTS kernel

Tags: debian, kernel, linux-kernel, lts

Is there a way to run **debian testing** (actual is bookworm) but with **LTS kernel**, something like in arch linux there is a `linux-lts` package. I want to avoid constantly jumping to very new kernel.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using one of the options below.

I installed the LTS kernel¹ 5.15.49 ( linux-image-5.15.49-xanmod1 ) on 3 different machines and so far I haven't had a problem.

1. XanMod Kernel - xanmod.org

   ```
   echo 'deb http://deb.xanmod.org releases main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xanmod-kernel.list
   wget -qO - https://dl.xanmod.org/gpg.key | sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/xanmod-kernel.gpg add -
   apt update
   ```
2. Liquorix kernel - liquorix.net.

   ```
   apt-get install lsb-release apt-transport-https -y
   mkdir -p /etc/apt/{sources.list.d,trusted.gpg.d}
   curl -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/liquorix-keyring.gpg 'https://liquorix.net/liquorix-keyring.gpg'
   echo "deb https://liquorix.net/debian testing main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/liquorix.list
   echo "deb-src https://liquorix.net/debian testing main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/liquorix.list
   apt update
   ```

**And...** there is also the possibility to merge² the Testing with the Bullseye³ to use a kernel like 5.14 or 5.15.

All the best.

---

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKMnt.png
2. https://rabexc.org/posts/apt-config (Be careful!)
3. https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=bullseye-backports&searchon=names&keywords=kernel-image

Comment: +1 good to know this options. I don't know if this is a good idea to install kernel from stable-backports in testing but definitely it is worth to check this xanmod and liquorix kernels. Also considering compiling from sources. Thanks.